# Error in your SQL syntax: Multiple Join Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have used multiple join tables. But I got a error. I can't understand. This is my code.

```
`SELECT cities.cities, address.village, address.phone
```

FROM tbl_join
INSERT JOIN cities ON tbl_join.id = cities.id
INSERT JOIN address ON tbl_join.id = address.id` And showing this error

```
`Error

SQL query: Documentation

SELECT cities.cities, address.village, address.phone

FROM tbl_join
INSERT JOIN cities ON tbl_join.id = cities.id
INSERT JOIN address ON tbl_join.id = address.id LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT JOIN cities ON tbl_join.id = cities.id
INSERT JOIN address ON tbl_join.i' at line 4`
```

Comment: `INSERT JOIN` isn't valid SQL syntax...did you mean `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @dale Burrell i am using MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `INNER JOIN` not `INSERT JOIN`

Comment: Kindly mark it as Answer if it solved your problem :)